# Removing duplicates *after* ordering in a SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, distinct

I have the following SQL query:

```
select 
    id,
    name
from
    project
    inner join job on project.id = job.project_id
where
    job.user_id = 'me'
order by
    project.modified desc
limit 10
```

The idea is to get information about the 10 most recently used projects for a given user.

The problem is that this can return duplicates in the case where multiple jobs have the same project. Instead of having duplicates, I want to order all rows by `modified desc`, remove duplicates based on `id` and `name`, *then* limit to 10.

I've not been able to figure out how to achieve this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just need `SELECT DISTINCT id, name FROM ...`

Comment: @eurotrash No, that doesn't work because I'm ordering by `modified`, which isn't in the columns being selected.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name They're in the `project` table. I'm not sure what you mean by using `exists`.

Comment: Doesn't matter, you can order by a column that isn't selected.

Comment: @eurotrash: not when it's missing from the `distinct` fields: `ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`. And adding it there makes no sense, because I'd no longer be de-duplicating by `id` and `name`.

Comment: Oh right, of course... has one of these answers worked for you then?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting duplicates because of the join. As you only want columns from the project table (I assume `id` and `name` are from that table), not creating the duplicates in the first place would be better than removing them after the join:

```
select p.id,
       p.name
from project p
where exists (select *
              from job job
              where job.project_id = p.id
                and job.user_id = 'me')
order by p.modified desc
limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

try this using row_number - it will work on postgresql

```
select * from 
(select 
    id,
    name,row_number() over(partition by id,name order by modified desc) as rn
from
    project inner join job on project.id = job.project_id
where
    job.user_id = 'me')a where rn=1 order by modified desc limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **SELECT DISTINCT**?

```
select distinct
    id,
    name
from
    project
    inner join job on project.id = job.project_id
where
    job.user_id = 'me'
order by
    project.modified desc
limit 10
```

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work because `modified` is not in the selected columns.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following, which seems to work fine:

```
select
    p.id,
    p.name
from
    project p
    inner join
    (
        select
            j.id,
            max(j.modified) as max_modified
        from
            job j
        where
            t.user_id = 'me'
        group by
            j.id
        order by
            max_modified desc
        limit 10
    ) ids on p.id = ids.id
order by
    max_modified desc
```